# Access material UI dropdown value in react and JSX

Tags: reactjs

So i'm fairly new to react and using a creative Tim template based on the material UI library. So far it's going well except I am stuck at what I expect to be a really silly hurdle. When logging event.target.value (as below) I can see the shape I have clicked but just don't know how to access it.

C*onsole Screenshot*

[image]

This is my parent code

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
    }

  myFunc(event) {
    console.log("test");
    console.log(event.target.value);
   }

      -- some other ui stuff above--- 

    <GridContainer justify = "center">
      <CustomDropdown
      buttonText="Select your shape!"
      buttonProps={{
      className: classes.navLink,
      color: "transparent"
      }}
      dropdownList={Names}
      onClick={this.myFunc}
      />
    </GridContainer>
```

This is the custom dropdown code, sorry I know it's long but didn't want to miss out code I thought was irrelevant when it wasn't.

```
class CustomDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };


    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({ open: !state.open }));

  }
  handleClose(param) {

    this.setState({ open: false });
    if(this.props && this.props.onClick){
      this.props.onClick(param);
    }
  }
  handleCloseAway = event => {
    if (this.anchorEl.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }
  render() {

    const { open } = this.state;
    const {
      classes,
      buttonText,
      buttonIcon,
      dropdownList,
      buttonProps,
      dropup,
      dropdownHeader,
      caret,
      hoverColor,
      left,
      rtlActive,
      noLiPadding
    } = this.props;
    const caretClasses = classNames({
      [classes.caret]: true,
      [classes.caretActive]: open,
      [classes.caretRTL]: rtlActive
    });
    const dropdownItem = classNames({
      [classes.dropdownItem]: true,
      [classes[hoverColor + "Hover"]]: true,
      [classes.noLiPadding]: noLiPadding,
      [classes.dropdownItemRTL]: rtlActive
    });
    let icon = null;
    switch (typeof buttonIcon) {
      case "function":
        icon = <this.props.buttonIcon className={classes.buttonIcon} />;
        break;
      case "string":
        icon = (
          <Icon className={classes.buttonIcon}>{this.props.buttonIcon}</Icon>
        );
        break;
      default:
        icon = null;
        break;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Button
            aria-label="Notifications"
            aria-owns={open ? "menu-list" : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            {...buttonProps}
            buttonRef={node => {
              this.anchorEl = node;
            }}
            onClick={this.handleClick}

          >
            {icon}
            {buttonText !== undefined ? buttonText : null}
            {caret ? <b className={caretClasses} /> : null}
          </Button>
        </div>
        <Popper
          open={open}
          anchorEl={this.anchorEl}
          transition
          disablePortal
          placement={
            dropup
              ? left ? "top-start" : "top"
              : left ? "bottom-start" : "bottom"
          }
          className={classNames({
            [classes.popperClose]: !open,
            [classes.pooperResponsive]: true
          })}
        >
          {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
            <Grow
              in={open}
              id="menu-list"
              style={
                dropup
                  ? { transformOrigin: "0 100% 0" }
                  : { transformOrigin: "0 0 0" }
              }
            >
              <Paper className={classes.dropdown}>
                <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleCloseAway}>
                  <MenuList role="menu" className={classes.menuList}>
                    {dropdownHeader !== undefined ? (
                      <MenuItem
                        onClick={this.handleClose}
                        className={classes.dropdownHeader}
                      >
                        {dropdownHeader}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ) : null}
                    {dropdownList.map((prop, key) => {
                      if (prop.divider) {
                        return (
                          <Divider
                            key={key}
                            onClick={this.handleClose}
                            className={classes.dropdownDividerItem}
                          />
                        );
                      }
                      return (
                        <MenuItem
                          key={key}
                          onClick={this.handleClose}
                          className={dropdownItem}

                        >
                          {prop}
                        </MenuItem>
                      );
                    })}
                  </MenuList>
                </ClickAwayListener>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          )}
        </Popper>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

CustomDropdown.defaultProps = {
  caret: true,
  hoverColor: "primary"
};

CustomDropdown.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  hoverColor: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "black",
    "primary",
    "info",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "danger",
    "rose"
  ]),
  buttonText: PropTypes.node,
  buttonIcon: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  dropdownList: PropTypes.array,
  buttonProps: PropTypes.object,
  dropup: PropTypes.bool,
  dropdownHeader: PropTypes.node,
  rtlActive: PropTypes.bool,
  caret: PropTypes.bool,
  left: PropTypes.bool,
  noLiPadding: PropTypes.bool,
  // function that retuns the selected item
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

export default withStyles(customDropdownStyle)(CustomDropdown);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your onClick handler like this:

```
   <MenuItem>
       key={key}
       **value={prop}**
       className={dropdownItem}
       **onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}**
    </MenuItem>
```

You can easily get the value of 'li' element.
There are different ways of getting the value of 'li' element, Below is one of them.

```
     function handleClick(event) {
       let value = event.target.getAttribute("value");
      console.log(value)// 'Rectangular'
     }
```